# Trivial torsion subgroup

Tags: elliptic-curves, torsion-groups

I am just wondering, suppose we have a curve $y^2 = x^3+ax + b$ defined over $\mathbb{Q}$ and suppose for simplicity $a,b \in \mathbb{Z}$. Can we say something about the torsion subgroup with the only information based on $a,b$? More precisely: can we say for sure that the torsion subgroup is trivial, based on some relation between $a$ and $b$?

Answer (score 1):

Since this is tagged as "Elliptic curves" I'm going to assume you meant $y^2= x^3+ax +b$.

The Nagell-Lutz Theorem gives that all torsion points have integer coordinates-- furthermore the $y$-coordinate of a torsion point necessarily divides the discriminant $D$, given by $-16 (4a^2 +27b^2)$ (in your case, since your elliptic curve is written in a form which implies it has characteristic $\ne 2$ or $3$.) So to compute the torsion subgroup we find all integers whose squares are factors of the discriminant. After you have found every such $y$, find each corresponding $x$-- if $x$ isn't an integer, then we can throw  away that point.

After we have found all integer points on the curve whose $y$-coordinates have squares dividing the discriminant, we look to Mazur's theorem, which says that if a point is of finite order, it must have order $n$, where $1 \le n \le 10$ or $n=12$. (This is an incredibly powerful result.) So we compute $nP$ for an integer point $P$, trying the values of $n$ given by Mazur's theorem. If $nP$ has non-integer coordinates for all the candidate $P$, then the torsion subgroup consists only of the point at infinity.

Hope this helped!

Comment: You mean $y^2=x^3+ax+b$ in the first line.

Comment: Ah, yes. Fixed.

Comment: Thank you for the Nagell-Lutz reference. From here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nagell–Lutz_theorem I understood that actually $y$ must duvide just $4a^3 + 27b^2$, isn't it? And why we need to consider integers whose squares divide the discriminant? Why cannot we just consider all $y$ such that $y | (4a^3 + 27b^2)$?

Comment: Some care is needed here: the N-L theorem does *not* say "all the torsion points have integer coordinates", but rather that all the **rational points which are torsion** have integer coordinates...and assuming the curve is non-singular and with integer coefficients, of course.

Comment: @DonAntonio But the curve is defined over $\mathbb{Q}$.

Comment: Still, @user112072. Many times one can be interested in checking for some fields extension to have more points on the curve. Of course, if you only want rational ones then you're fine.